# I'm not able to install Ubuntu server 12.04 on my computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server 12.04 using a usb flash drive.

I used a program called Universal USB Installer to generate a version bootable on the drive. Until this point is all right.

During the installation, the system is trying to "load installer components from CD" and gives an error. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What is the error it gives?

Comment: Failed to copy file from CD.

Comment: Please read here: 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/127398/usb-drive-install-of-ubuntu-12-04-server-fails-cant-find-components-from-cd-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree and have installed Ubuntu several times using PenDrive which is recommended. There is now a seemingly better way using this [Ubuntu USB Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
If you want to run the tried and true PenDrive installer go [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
This stuff usually always works, just that a USB is a little slower.

Comment: Yeah, finally i installed Ubuntu server using your tutorials. Thanks a lot.

Comment: right on.. the ubuntu forums are a good place to ask these types of questions as the development community is on those boards. Also "AskUbuntu" is a good place for Ubuntu flavored linux details.

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential points of failure in installing in the method you are trying:

1) You could have not safely removed the USB drive (as in unmounted) before taking it out. Assuming you disconnected it of course.

2) The USB formatting utility did not do it properly the first time. Sometimes I need to use different utilities to do the same thing depending on the distribution.

3) The ISO you downloaded did not download properly.

4) Your uSB drive is damaged.

One common misconception is that some USB drives are incapable of booting any OS, be it an install source, or another. I have never seen this first hand and am highly dubious of such claims.

Booting from USB is both convenient and typically fast. If you have further issues you may just want to abandon it for now and revert to traditional optical media.

Comment: Maybe the best thing to do is install via optical media. I'll do this. Thanks for help.

Comment: I lost 15 rep for this being unaccepted? What?